# sftp m@10.1.1.2 exec: /opt/bin/ssh: No such file or directory Connection closed

Tags: sftp

**I've just installed openssh-sftp-client - 7.6p1-1 and for whatever reason I cannot sftp to any servers even though it shows it is installed and its apparently a command.
I can SSH fine just no SFTP**

**Here I show the package list with open-ssh-client installed:**

```
[/] # uname -v
opkg list-installed
entware-opt - 222108-5
findutils - 4.6.0-1
ldconfig - 2.23-6
libc - 2.23-6
libgcc - 6.3.0-6
libopenssl - 1.0.2n-1
libpthread - 2.23-6
librt - 2.23-6
libssp - 6.3.0-6
libstdcpp - 6.3.0-6
locales - 2.23-6
openssh-sftp-client - 7.6p1-1
opkg - 2011-04-08-9c97d5ec-17a
terminfo - 6.0-1c
zlib - 1.2.11-1
```

**Here I show the fact that the SFTP client is actually executable as far as I know:**

```
[/] # sftp
usage: sftp [-46aCfpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
          [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit]
          [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
          [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
```

**Here I show that SSH works perfectly fine to another server:**

```
[/] # ssh m@10.1.1.2
The authenticity of host '10.1.1.2 (10.1.1.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.1.1.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
m@10.1.1.2's password:
Linux XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**But when I attempt to run sftp I'm presented with this:**

```
[/] # sftp m@10.1.1.2
exec: /opt/bin/ssh: No such file or directory
Connection closed
```

**Do I have to edit the sshd_config file under:**

```
 # override default of no subsystems
 Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
 Subsystem       sftp    /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Entware-ng/bin

 AllowUsers admin
 # Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
 #Match User anoncvs
```

**Any help would be appreciated.
thx
Mike**

Comment: Maybe the problem is just as it says? The file or directory does not exist... have you tried just sftp root@10.1.1.2 and navigating interactively?

Comment: Is the client side actually an Ubuntu system? `opkg` makes it look like it isn't, and I don't think `openssh-sftp-client` is a standard Ubuntu package either (`sftp` is provided by `openssh-client`)

Comment: Its a QNAP box actually...I thought it was based off of UBUNTU. opkg doesn't scream that it does. If I'm in the wrong thread I apologize. UNAME says just LINUX.

Comment: I FIXED IT!!!!

I just added a symlink to /usr//etc/ssh
         
`code`
ln -s /usr/bin/ssh ssh